# "Мы спасём мир!" или как контролировать исполнение процесса

Tags: c#, .net

У вас есть exe-файл. Если вы его запустите, то может произойти следующее:

1. либо вы спасаете мир от 3-ей мировой войны (программка активирует нанороботов, которые уничтожат всё оружие воюющих сторон)
2. либо эта программа на самом деле - вирус, который удалит всю информацию, историю, достижения за всё время существования человечества, хранящуюся на компе, где этот вирус находится.

Как запустить эту программку не боясь за уничтожение информации?

**P.S.** Грубо говоря: у нас есть exe-файл, который необходимо запустить, но мы не знаем что он может сделать. Хотелось бы ограничить его возможности, чтобы он, например, не смог перезагрузить комп или завершить процесс или вообще разрешить ему работать только с файлами в единственном каталоге (например, в домашнем).

Comment: нужно именно программными средствами .NET сделать такую вещь

Comment: Т. е. сам написал, а функционал не знаешь, и надо проверить, или песочницу самому писать?

Comment: т.е. тебе отправили exe-файл (по email) и ты не знаешь что он может сделать. Он может, например, удалить все файлы с компа, а может и не удалить. Но запустить его нужно (например с помощью Process.Start). Вопрос в том: как программно (в .NET, язык C#) разрешить ему работать только с теми файлами, которые я захочу, и запретить ему выключать windows. Главное, что если программа попробует нарушить правила, то ничего у неё не получиться. Своеобразный запуск в "безопасной среде" для компа, на котором осуществляется этот запуск.

Comment: По сути вопрос *как написать антивирус ?*.

Comment: у каспера есть режим песочницы и хватит автору баловаться легкими наркотиками

Comment: Запустить его от имени пользователя с ограниченными правами, типа гостя?

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov А если этот код запускается на сервере IIS? Не все хостинги предоставляют возможность работы с несколькими пользователями, да?

Comment: `root@localhost$ ./SaveTheWorld.exe --let-it-all-end --no-cheerleaders`

и, к сведению, Третья Мировая уже окончена

Comment: Бррр... Т.е. вы это хотите еще и на shared hosting'е запустить? А с чего вы тогда взяли, что вам вообще удастся на произвольном хостинге  запустить произвольный unmanaged code?

Comment: И что, при этом удавалось перезагрузить сервер хостера?

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, уже запускал. Перезагрузить может и нет, а кто мешает этому exe-шнику "расшарить" или даже удалить файлы сайта?

Comment: Ограничить доступ к файловой системе и запустить приложение в песочнице - это две совершенно разные задачи. Первая решается элементарно путем установки соответствующих прав на запись.

Answer (score 11):

[Практическое руководство. Выполнение не вполне безопасного кода в изолированной среде](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb763046.aspx)

[AppDomain - класс](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.appdomain.aspx) + [PermissionSet - класс](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.permissionset.aspx) + [CodeAccessPermission - класс](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.codeaccesspermission.aspx)

Пример - ораничение разрешений на конкретный каталог в PermissionSet'е:

```
    permissionset.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, @"c:\Users\Homedir\SandboxFolder"));
```

Так-же гляньте: [Managed Sandbox](http://managedsandbox.codeplex.com/)

**UPD:**

Вот простейший пример песочницы для какого-то консольного приложения, которому нужно открывать файлы (`System.IO.File.OpenRead`) на диске:

```
using System;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Security.Policy;

class Sandboxer
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string programmname = "angryprogramm.exe";    // Это программа которая хочет прочитать все наши файлы

        Console.WriteLine("Сейчас мы сделаем попытку выполнить программу " + programmname + " с ограничением доступа");
        Console.Write("Разрешить доступ программы к файлам? [y/n]: ");
        bool allow = (Convert.ToChar(Console.Read()).ToString() == "y");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        // минимальный набор разрешений для консольного приложения
        PermissionSet permissionset = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);   // По умолчанию всё запрещено
        permissionset.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));  // Разрешение на выполнение программы :-)
        permissionset.AddPermission(new UIPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));            // Разрешение на UI

        // Если разрешаем доступ к файлам
        if(allow)
        {
            permissionset.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));    // Разрешение на неограниченный доступ к файлам
        }

        // Настройка песочницы
        AppDomainSetup domaininfo = new AppDomainSetup();
        domaininfo.ApplicationBase = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;

        AppDomain sandbox = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Sandbox", new Evidence() , domaininfo, permissionset);

        try
        {
            sandbox.ExecuteAssembly(programmname);
            Console.WriteLine("Всё получилось и программа выполнилась!");

        }catch(SecurityException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ничего не получилось: " + e.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

А в качестве песочницы для native - как вариант поставить виртуалку. Настолько тонко контролировать разрешения вы конечно же не сможете, но зато (при правильной настройке), программа вряд ли сможет вылезти из ВМ и удалить всю информацию, историю и достижения за всё время существования человечества, хранящиеся на хост-компьютере.

Comment: Это же для управляемого кода только?

Comment: Да. Есть флаг, дающий разрешение на запуск неуправляемого кода:

    permissionset.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode));

Comment: А как эти правила применить к Process.Start()?

Comment: > Да. Есть флаг, дающий разрешение на запуск неуправляемого кода:

А что, на запущенный неуправляемый код будут действовать все те-же пермишены?

Comment: [SecurityPermissionFlag Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.securitypermissionflag.aspx)

> UnmanagedCode Ability to call unmanaged code.
> Since **unmanaged code potentially allows other permissions to be bypassed**, this is a dangerous permission that should only be granted to highly trusted code. It is used for such applications as calling native code using PInvoke or using COM interop.

Comment: > А что, на запущенный неуправляемый код будут действовать все те-же пермишены?
Нет, конечно-же не будут. На то он и неуправляемый код, в рамках системы разрешений .NET его можно или запретить совсем или полностью разрешить. 
Как вы процитировали ниже, это разрешение стоит применять только при особой необходимости.